# Cant access class object variable of javascript in IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a class in javascript , in which i have defined few properties and methods and i have created an array and created and instance values of the class and pushed into it. After that i have iterated the array and checked a property from a particular method, but in IE and mozilla it is showing as undefined. I have given below the code for your details.

Class:

```
function DateDetail(date, isBefore, isAfter, isNow) {
this.Date = date;
this.MonthNo = this.Date.getMonth();
this.DayNo = this.Date.getDate();
this.Year = this.Date.getFullYear();
this.IsAfter = isAfter;
this.IsBefore = isBefore;
this.IsNow = isNow;
this.GetMonthValue = function () {
    return this.Date.toString("MMM-yyyy");
    };
}
```

Method

```
function GetTableDataClass(data) {
if (data.IsAfter)
    return "after";
else if (data.IsBefore)
    return "before";
else if (data.IsNow)
    return "now";
else
    return " ";
}
```

Calling method

```
GetTableDataClass(item)
```

I am getting data is undefined in mozilla and IE. Please let me know any suggestions.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the item variable?

Comment: I am getting it from the array

Comment: You accepted an answer for 6 questions out of the 28 you asked.

Comment: @Lokesh How do you instantiate each one?

Comment: what does console.log("item:",item);GetTableDataClass(item); print to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting that `data` is undefined, your problem is that the value of `item` that you are passing to `GetTableDataClass` is undefined. You have to note that in JavaScript `undefined` is a value that a variable can have (just like `null` in C#).

If you are getting `item` from an array make sure the index you are getting exists. If the index doesn't exists it will return `undefined`. (ex.: `var a = [1,2,3]; alert(a[3])` this will alert `undefined`).

Comment: -> I can able to see the contents in google chrome. Only in mozilla and IE i could not able to view the content. Is there any other issue other than what you have mentioned.

Comment: @Lokesh To be honest at this point, it's just reading in a crystal ball. You should show relevant part of your script where you initialize `item` and call `GetTableDataClass`.